# Take last row first item from two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this two-dimensional array and I am trying to take the first item of the last row, which in this case would be 5, but I can't find out how to get this.

```
int[][] arr = { { 2, 4, 5, 1 }, { 4, 8, 7, 1 }, { 5, 9, 2, 20 } };`
```

This is what I've tried, but this gives me the last item of the row.

```
String[] lastNum = arr[arr.length - 1];
System.out.println(lastNum[lastNum.length-1]);
```

Comment: So select the first item: `lastNum[0]`.

Comment: Try `lastNum[0]`

Comment: And `lastNum` is an `int[]`, not a `String[]`.

Comment: You're selecting the last item of the last row. @AndyTurner is right, `lastNum[0]`.

Comment: `int lastRowFirstElement = arr[arr.length-1][0]`

Comment: Oh yeah lastNum[0] works thanks, stupid that i didn't came up with that

Comment: `[help-me]` `lastNum` would be better named `lastRow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line index is     `arr.length - 1`, the first item of it is `0`, you can print it with

```
System.out.println(arr[arr.length - 1][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the last element in `lastNum` which is why that's what you're seeing. Also, your typing is wrong for `lastNum` based on `arr`.

```
int[] lastNum = arr[arr.length - 1];
System.out.println(lastNum[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, cannot see the reason that you are doing this :

```
String[] lastNum = arr[arr.length - 1];
System.out.println(lastNum[lastNum.length-1]);
```

Even if you wanted to do so, you would have to replace `String` with `int` because your `arr` array has integer arrays in it. 
Also, you would have to use `System.out.println(lastNum[0]);` because the one you used will print 20 which is the last element of your integer "inner" array.

A very easy way to do that as Neng Liu commented, would be this:

```
System.out.println(arr[arr.length - 1][0]);
```